# C# read cyrillic

Tags: c#, character-encoding

Hello guys for example when I open with notepad a text file it's shows for example this characters (for me is ok this output)

```
"ÍÜÞ ËÀÉÍ ÑÈÍÅÌÀ"
"ÕÅÐÎÍ ÊÎÌÌÜÞÍÈÊÅÉØÍÇ"
```

But when I trying to read it with C#

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
     textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

It shows

```
"��� ���� ������"
"����� ��������������"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the right encoding to `File.ReadAllText`:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName, encoding);
```

However, you'll need to either *know* the encoding beforehand, or work it out with heuristics (there'll always be a chance you'll get the wrong one).

For your real use case, do you know what the encoding will be?

Comment: I needed to read Cyrillic, then convert it manually to correct form (russian), and then save it as utf-8

Comment: Thank you very much it worked... I put textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName, Encoding.Default) and know is all ok